# Textext jquery plugin doesn't work with Multiple TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-textext

I'm using [Textext](http://textextjs.com/) Jquery plugin in a table,
every row has a textarea to let the user choose params.

All the textareas initialize and but they don't work and only in the last row the textarea works as expected. in the rest I can't even add any text to the textarea input.

this is my HTML:

```
 <td class="cat-params-container col-lg-4">
     <textarea id="params_{{ c['id'] }}" name="params" class="textarea-params" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
```

and the JS initialize:

```
$('.textarea-params').textext({ plugins: 'tags' });
```

Comment: I think all textareas class names must be different

Comment: Try making a fiddle :)

Comment: I tested my code some more,
I use Jquery UI sortable functionality on the table, and that destroys the textarea for some reason....

once I disabled it, everything worked...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this plugin creates an absolutely positioned wrapper `div.text-wrap` thus textareas overlay each other.

Try disabling this e.g. like so:

```
.text-wrap {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/qdqf5ygu/)